# More than one ValidationError in Admin ModelForm in Django

Tags: django, admin, django-1.5, validationerror

I have a model that the clean that raises a ValidationError in the model, and then I customized the form in the admin. The "myfield" is a ForeingKey.

```
class MyModel(models.Models):
     myfield = models...

     def clean(self):
         if check_something_on(self.myfield):
             raise ValidationError("Technical Error in myfield")
     def save(self, *kwargs):
         self.clean()
         super(MyModel, self).save(*kwargs)
```

I expect that by the shell system or other methods, the myfield field is always OK.

Then, I added in the admin a form that looks like this:

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myfield = form...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyModelAdminForm, self).clean()
        myfield = cleaned_data['myfield']
        if check_something_on(myfield):
            forms.ValidationError("User helping Error in myfield")
        return cleaned_data
```

What happens is that in the admin page, I end up with both messages, the technical error and the user helping error...

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: You should definitely not be calling clean from within save.

Comment: Why not? I mean, its a way to guarantee the data is OK, I've seen the pattern working and describen in other places